# syntax error on token "]", VariableDeclaratorld expected after this token

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, processing

I am trying to pass thistime[] to class and use it to define width and height of two rects.This is just a simplified version of my initial code and I get the errorsyntax error on token "]", VariableDeclaratorld expected after this token", here are my code:

```
ArrayList textlines;

int xpos=20;
int ypos=20;
int[]thistime = new int[2];

void setup() {
  size(1200, 768);
  textlines = new ArrayList();
  thistime[0] =3;
  thistime[1] =30;
}

void draw() {
}


void mousePressed() {
  textlines.add(new Line(xpos, ypos,thistime));
  for (int i=0; i<textlines.size(); i++) {

    Line p=(Line)textlines.get(i);
    p.display();
  }
}


class Line {

  int x;
  int y;
  int thatimee[];

  Line(int xpo, int ypo, int thetimee[]) {
    x =xpo;
    y =ypo;
    thatimee[]= new int[thetimee.length];
    thatimee[0]=thetimee[0];
    thatimee[1]=thetimee[1];
  }

  void display() {
    fill(50, 50, 50);
    rect(random(width), random(height), thatimee[0],thatimee[0] );
    rect(random(width), random(height), thatimee[1], thatimee[1]);
  }
}
```

The error is in the line

```
thatimee[]= new int[thetimee.length];
```

Who knows the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Line(int xpo, int ypo, int thetimee[]) {
    x = xpo;
    y = ypo;
    thatimee = new int[thetimee.length];
    thatimee[0] = thetimee[0];
    thatimee[1] = thetimee[1]; 
}
```

You already declared the variable "thatimee" as an array up there, remove the "[]" within the scope of Line when initializing the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the [] in the assignment. like this:

```
thattimee = new int[thetimee.length];
```

Answer (score 2):

just use

```
thatimee = new int[thetimee.length];
```

the [] is for declaring an array. It should not be used while initializing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put `thatimee[]` when initializing the array. You simply put:

```
thatimee = new int[thetimee.length];
```

`thatimee` represents the handle of the array, and you are storing something in the handle.